# Python high precision integer to array of numpy integer

Tags: python, numpy, bignum

I understand that `numpy` can't handle non-native integers, but **how can I store python high precision integers as an `array` of native integers** (in either endian)? e.g.

```
a = 105951305240504794066266398962584786593081186897777398483830058739006966285013
```

can't be stored as a native integer because it's `256` bit. But it can be stored as

```
A = array([18196013122530525909, 15462736877728584896,
           12869567647602165677, 16879016735257358861], dtype=uint64)
```

using little-endian (i.e. `a == A[0] + A[1]<<64 + A[2]<<128 + A[3]<<192`) or `A[::-1]` as big-endian. How can I convert from `a` to `A` here?

I want to convert this "python-side" number to "numpy-side" so that I can run highly efficient algorithms on it (e.g. *fast multiplication using Fourier transform*).

I believe Python internally should already be using similar structure. All I need to do is to "expose" it to `numpy`, but I'm not sure about the exact structure or how can I "expose" it. The most straight forward way is of course using a `while` loop:

```
A = np.zeros(4, 'uint64')
i = 0
while a > 0:
    A[i] = a & (2**64-1)
    a  >>= 64
    i   += 1
```

But I'm wondering are there more "native" or "efficient" ways?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you simplify your question a little? 
I have no problem defining `a` and multiplying them using `np.array(a)*np.array(a)`.

Comment: @Miladiouss The result of `np.array(a)` is actually an `object` array. Which is still internally a python big number. As long as the number is still an `object`, it is processed by python (slowly) and cannot be used to experiment a lot of algorithms involving partitioning big number to small machine-size numbers.

Comment: You can use `int.to_bytes()` and `int.from_bytes()` to get integer into a base-256 form. You can then relatively easily convert the byte arrays into bases like the base 2**64 in your example.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thanks, that helped a lot! I can use `np.array([a.to_bytes(32,'little')]).view('P')` to do the conversion now

Comment: How does one apply rudimentary operations on this new array and how could you convert it back to the python bignum?