# Numpy 256-bit computing

Tags: python, numpy

I have some large numbers that I am using for Elliptic Curve Cryptography. So far I have been doing all the computations in plain python which natively support arbitrary sized numbers by the use of "bignum" integer type. However, I would like to vectorize some of these operations (for performance reasons) and would like to use an array containing 256 bit unsigned integers. But AFAIK the maximum size of an integer in numpy is 64-bits by using `np.longlong` (or `np.ulonglong` for the unsigned version). An idea from [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775293/python-high-precision-integer-to-array-of-numpy-integer) was to represent each 256-bit number as an array with four 64-bit integers:

```
large = 105951305240504794066266398962584786593081186897777398483830058739006966285013
arr = np.array([large.to_bytes(32,'little')]).view('P')
arr
```

Output:

```
array([18196013122530525909, 15462736877728584896, 12869567647602165677,
       16879016735257358861], dtype=uint64)
```

And I can convert it back to native python "bignum" by doing:

```
int.from_bytes(arr.tobytes(), 'little')
```

Output:

```
105951305240504794066266398962584786593081186897777398483830058739006966285013
```

However, I would like to do some operations before converting it back to "bignum":

```
arr2 = arr + 1
int.from_bytes(arr2.tobytes(), 'little')
```

Output:

```
105951305240504794072543500697971467357257258687906003363414235534976478560982
```

Which is ofcourse not equal to `large + 1`

---

Is it possible to handle 256-bit numbers in numpy? If not, does there exist any suitable workarounds?

Comment: Python supports arbitrary precision integers using the `int` integer type. What is `bignum`? Also, don't forget language tags

Comment: You'll have to effectively implement all the operations yourself. At that point, it's probably faster/easier to write directly in C, since you can bypass python's loops, which you would need to e.g. carry over digits.

Comment: "vectorize" in the fast(er) `numpy` sense means using the compiled `numpy` methods.  If those methods are only compiled for `int64`, you won't get any speed by trying to work around them.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `arr + 1`, do `arr + [0, 0, 0, 1]`

Comment: @hpaulj. Depends on how you do it though

Comment: @MadPhysicist I mean arbitrary precision integers, I think python represents large integers (>32 bit?) by using some kind of fragmented array: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-python-represents-integers-using-bignum-f8f0574d0d6b This sequence is referred to as ```bignum```. I could implement it directly in C, but I would like to know what other options exist.

Comment: @MadPhysicist is ```arr + [0, 0, 0, 1]``` correct? It seems to render the ```dtype``` to ```dtype('float64')``` for me.

Comment: @Kevin. Then `arr + np.array([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=np.uint64)`

Comment: @hpaulj. I've posted an answer that's reasonably vectorized for addition. There's a loop for digit carry, but that's unlikely to overwhelm the computation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a couple of arrays of four bytes:

```
a = np.array([0b0000_1000, 0b1000_1100, 0b0111_1111, 0b1111_0000], dtype=np.uint8)  # [  8, 140, 127, 240]
b = np.array([0b1111_0000, 0b1111_0000, 0b1111_0000, 0b1111_0000], dtype=np.uint8)  # [240, 240, 240, 240]
```

Now you want to add them up and get something like

```
c = np.array([0b1111_1001, 0b0111_1101, 0b0111_0000, 0b1110_0000], dtype=np.uint8)  # [249, 125, 112, 224]
```

I've deliberately avoided something that requires carrying over in the topmost byte. In this case the result was computed with

```
ai = int.from_bytes(a.tobytes(), byteorder='big')
bi = int.from_bytes(b.tobytes(), byteorder='big')
c = np.frombuffer((ai + bi).to_bytes(4, 'big'), dtype=np.uint8)
```

So how to do that without converting to and from `int`? You can't do a naive `c = a + b`:

```
[1111_1000, 0111_1100, 0110_1111, 1110_0000]
          +1         +1         +1
```

Notice that the carries at the marked locations were all dropped. You can check for carries without triggering overflow using

```
0xFF - a < b
```

The good news is that you can only ever carry over one bit per byte: `0xFF + 0xFF + 1 == 0x1FF`. You also can't carry over from adding 1 if the sum just carried over: `(0xFF + 0xFF) & 0xFF == 0xFE`. Here is a simple implementation of proper addition:

```
c = a.copy()
while b.sum():
    carry = np.r_[0xFF - c[1:] < b[1:], False].view(np.uint8)
    c += b
    b = carry
```

This loop will generally run for 1-2 iterations. In the absolute worst-case, it may run for up to N-1 iterations, where `N=256` in your case, or `N=4` in this example. Using a larger datatype will mean that you can reduce the number of iterations in the worst case (and probably speed up the best case too). The only caveat that you won't be able to use the `...view(np.uint8)` trick to convert your boolean mask. But that's actually a blessing in disguise, because you can write

```
c = a.copy()
carry = np.zeros_like(a)
cbuf = carry.view(bool)[::a.itemsize]
# On big-endian use this instead:
#cbuf = carry.view(bool)[a.itemsize - 1::a.itemsize]
cbuf = cbuf[:-1]
m = np.iinfo(a.dtype).max
while b.sum():
    c += b
    np.less(m - c[1:], b[1:], out=cbuf)
    b = carry
```

Notice that this version not only avoids reallocating the carry buffer, but is completely agnostic to the `itemsize` of `a` and `b`.

### Exercises for the reader:

- Handling little-endian order correctly (my examples have the words arranged in big-endian order, unlike the question)
- Adding sign support (comes out of the box if you have fixed-width twos-complement)
- Actually vectorizing this operation across N dimensions
- Implementing operations like multiplication